# How do I remove additional link from website if after parsing in PHP, the Video URL is also extracted. And also the href attribute is javascript

Tags: video, youtube

I am trying to remove URL a sort of YouTube downloader that takes a YouTube video url, uses requests and show the video URL in address bar while downloading of that video from an online video downloader.

Website Used: https://ssyoutube.ch/

When you paste the Youtube video URL to download the video, it shows that link browser address bar also with the example like: "https://ssyoutube.ch/en73rf/#url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=libKVRa01L8" instead of like this: "https://ssyoutube.ch/en73rf/" the video URL is not to b shown.

Working with this script i hav checked all the files and found the data in "main.js" a Javascript file, and tried to do as i need, but it didn't work.

showLoader();removeHash();window.location.**replace("#url="+b);var e**;fetch(siteUrl+"/wp-json/aio-dl/video-data/",f).then(function(c){e=c.status;
return c.text()}).then(function(c){c=JSON.parse(c);void 0===c.error?showResult(c)

How do I remove the link from this href="javascript
I looked into this SO question but it doesnt help me because I cant find the onClick attribute